# "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'" while searching for a user by their name in a Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to search for a user by their name in a Flutter and Firebase project, but I am getting an exception and unable to display the user in my search results.

```
void onSearch() async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  setState(() {
    isLoad = true;
  });
  await firestore
      .collection('User')
      .where('firstName', isEqualTo: searchController.text)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    setState(() {
      userMap = value.docs[0].data();
      isLoad = false;
    });
    print(userMap);
  });
}
```

I have a TextField widget where the user can enter a search query. I am using Firebase Firestore to store my user data, and I want to search for users whose name matches the search query entered by the user. I am using a StreamBuilder widget to retrieve the user data from Firebase Firestore and display it in a ListView. When I enter a search query and try to filter the user data, I am getting an exception saying:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Comment: On which line does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

converts the search query to a string value using toString() method. i've provided below code you can try. This should fix the issue and allow you to search for users by their name.

```
void onSearch() async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  setState(() {
    isLoad = true;
  });
  await firestore
      .collection('User')
      .where('firstName', isEqualTo: searchController.text.toString())
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    setState(() {
      userMap = value.docs[0].data();
      isLoad = false;
    });
    print(userMap);
  });
}
```